Trying to redirect water in a lowered basement room by making a channel?
A few years ago we had a contractor lower the floor of one part of our basement.  We currently use it as a gym.
The issue is that once a year or so, only for about a day, we get so much rain that the water table rises up.  The water then floods into the lowered basement room via the perimeter of the floor, through the very very small crack between the original foundation, and the new lowered floor.
To get it out of the way, I do not want to cut out the perimeter and put in a French drain.  This is out of our budget and ability to do, and is not the point of this question, although I appreciate that it is the most guaranteed way to divert water.  Instead, I have an idea, and am curious if it would work, and perhaps some advice here would help.
I did install a sump pump, right next to this room.  It is lowered below the lowered floor level, to ensure that it gathers water from below the gym floor.  However, it on its own, does not do anything to help the flooding.
When the rains hit peak like once a year, the room will slowly fill up like a bowl of water.  The room is pretty big, like 20 feet by 15 feet approximately.  We have rubber flooring and all the furniture is and equipment is either elevated or not an issue.
I'd like to DIVERT the water, rather than continue to make attempts to prevent the water.  My idea, is to use a "Wall Chaser", to create a 3/4 inch deep, 1" wide channel, around the entire perimeter of the room.  Then have it meet at one end, that would have a drain leads right into the sump pump.  Then the rubber flooring can simply sit right over the channel hiding it from sight.
I'm just not sure if making a channel will help at all, or if it'll just fill with water as well, and it'll basically be as though I had nothing at all there.  I could tier the channel, like stair step, every few feet, so I could start at 1/2 inch on one end of the room, and lower it a little at a time every few feet.
We had a contractor almost destroy our home several years ago, and we've basically spent our entire life's savings repairing the damage he caused.  So we cannot afford a major installation of something like a French drain or drain tile system.  So I am searching for a solution that is cost effective.
We live in a very old neighborhood, the house itself over 100 years old.  There are no options for digging around the exterior of the house, as there are driveways, and cement paths, and the properties are right up against one another.  It would be way more trouble than it's worth to do that sort of thing on this property, which is one of the challenges I have faced in this situation.  All of the drains have been checked, diagnosed the situation, and we're confident of where the water is coming from.
I am not concerned about the flooding happening, because it is never for more than one or two days maximum, and there is nothing that can really be damaged in the room.  I just want to prevent it from filling up, and having to get a small pump and pump out the room when it happens.  Instead, I want to simply divert the water into the sump pump, in the most cost effective way.  It takes very little time for the room to dry after this, and I have fans and dehumidifiers etc that I use when the events take place.  I hope that is enough info to cover it!  I have a simple diagram (not to scale) that I have included here.
Any help or advice on this specific solution would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks 

Your solution could work.  The unknown is, if the channels can divert enough water fast enough so the water does not go over the chanels and across the floor, negating the solution.

I have the same response as RMDman's. It's really hard to predict what water will do in a situation like this. It might just fill the channel (because maybe things aren't as level as you think or the flow is too fast or a spider built a web or whatever) and foil all your best laid plans. Try and see, I guess.

If you can't dig outside, can you divert the water on the surface to the street, or otherwise away from the house?
